# Use custom jQuery function on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, function, dry

So I am trying to follow the DRY rule with this following script. Basically I would like an easy way to use a function on multiple elements. Currently the following will only work on last one specified and not all three of them. I tried putting this into a plugin with no luck. Still somewhat new to jQuery, any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a basic working fiddle of what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/947E5/

```
jQuery(function($) {

    hideShowMetaBoxes = function( page ){

        var tempID = '#page_template'
            template = 'templates/' + page + '.php',
            metabox = '#' + page + '_options';

        if ($(tempID).val() == template) {
            $(metabox).show();
            $(metabox+'-hide').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(metabox).hide();
            $(metabox+'-hide').prop('checked', false);
        }

        $(tempID).change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == template) {
                $(metabox).show();
                $(metabox+'-hide').prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $(metabox).hide();
                $(metabox+'-hide').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });

    };

    // Contact Options
    hideShowMetaBoxes('contact');

    // Meet Us Options
    hideShowMetaBoxes('meet_us');

    // Services Options
    hideShowMetaBoxes('services');

});
```

Comment: would be great if you can create the fiddle..

Comment: I wish I could. It is for Wordpress, when using page templates that have special options. This will show/hide the specified options according to the page template selected.

Comment: i am sure you could. you just need to add the dom and script in fiddle.

Comment: Built a basic model and posted the fiddle above.

Comment: Are you fine if modify few ids in the dom??

Comment: The HTML markup needs to stay the same. Only control I have is the javascript.

Comment: I have added the code and fiddle. let me know if you are ok with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified some dom( i. e. added the classes to div you are showing).
Here is the script:

```
jQuery(function($) {

hideShowMetaBoxes = function( page ){
    $('.templateoption').hide();//added for hidingd all template option divs

    var tempID = '#page_template'
        template = 'templates/' + page + '.php',
        metabox = '#' + page + '_options';

    if ($(tempID).val() == template) {
        $(metabox).show();
        $(metabox+'-hide').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(metabox).hide();
        $(metabox+'-hide').prop('checked', false);
    }
     };
});
$('#page_template').change(function(){
 hideShowMetaBoxes($("#page_template option:selected").text().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"_"));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/947E5/1/)**